# assignment from incompatible pointer type in list program

Tags: c, list, pointers

I am tring to create a program which can create lists in C (variable length arrays) but when I compile my code says I have a "assignment from incompatible pointer type" error

The errors are on these lines:

```
list_item *last = l->first;
last = last->next;
last->next = item;
```

Code:

```
typedef struct{
    struct list_item *next;
    void *data;
} list_item;

typedef struct{
    list_item *first;
    unsigned int len;
} list;

list *new_list(){
    list *l = (list *) malloc(sizeof(list));
    l->first = NULL;
    l->len = 0;
    return l;
}

list_item *new_list_item(){
    list_item *item = (list_item *) malloc(sizeof(list_item));
    item->next = NULL;
    item->data = NULL;
    return item;
}

void add_to_list(list *l, void *data){
    if(l == NULL || data == NULL){
        return;
    }

    list_item *item = new_list_item();
    item->data = data;

    int i;
    list_item *last = l->first;
    for(i = 0; i < l->len; i++){
        last = last->next;
    }   

    last->next = item;
    l->len++;
}
```

Comment: and where is the error?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: `struct list_item *next;`...how? there is no `struct list_item` there...

Comment: what do you mean? you can reference a pointer to the struct you are creating like this in a typedef

Comment: It doesn't look like you added all your code (`add_to_list` is missing some lines).  Also, you should include the complete error that you are seeing, including line numbers and other data that is being generated.

Comment: it is missing no lines but here are my errors:

Comment: list.c: In function ‘add_to_list’:
list.c:36:8: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   last = last->next;
        ^
list.c:39:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  last->next = item;
             ^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error you reference is being caused by this:

```
typedef struct {
    struct list_item *next;
    void *data;
} list_item;
```

This is creating an anonymous structure (**not** one named `list_item`) and then giving that anonymous structure the typedef'd name `list_item`.  If you need to self reference, you should do:

```
typedef struct list_item {
    struct list_item *next;
    void *data;
} list_item;
```

You have other errors that you've not mentioned though.  For instance, you're trying to dereference a `NULL` pointer:

```
list_item *last = l->first;
for(i = 0; i < l->len; i++){
    last = last->next;
}
```

The first time you add something to the list, `l->first` is `NULL` which means `last` is NULL and `l->len` is 0 so the loop doesn't execute.  Then you do:

```
last->next = item;
```

which dereferences the `NULL` pointer and crashes your application.

Assuming you fix that problem, you'll hit the next one in this loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < l->len; i++){
    last = last->next;
}
```

After this loop is done, last will be `NULL` again.  And `last->next = item` will be executed causing a segfault again.  You actually need to stop one short so you can assign the next pointer correctly.

If you replace:

```
int i;
list_item *last = l->first;
for(i = 0; i < l->len; i++){
    last = last->next;
}
```

with:

```
if (! l->first) {
    l->first = item;
} else {
    unsigned int i;
    list_item *last = l->first;
    for (i = 0; i < l->len-1; i++) {
        last = last->next;
    }
    last->next = item;
}
```

Then things will work much better.

Comment: It sure would be nice to know why someone felt the need to downvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First in add_to_list you need to check if l->first is null (the list is empty) because later you tried to access last->next but last was null in this case.

Also the function add_to_list accepts only void* as data so if you want to add anything else you should make a typecast

ex:

add_to_list(l, (void*)4) in case of a number or

add_to_list(l, (void*)struct something);

Comment: Please don't advocate things like `add_to_list(l, (void *) 4)`.  That's creating a pointer to the location 4 in memory, and it's just plain bad practice--and it's being really sneaky in trying to use the data pointer as a place to store actual data rather than a pointer to the data.  And there's also the issue of whether sizeof(pointer) is large enough to hold sizeof(data).  Think about data being longs or long long, or long doubles.  There are a number of situations where you can lose data because the storage space for a pointer isn't large enough and your cast is hiding that fact.

Comment: Maybe you can show the actual errors from the error list or debugger